# VSCode: 'parameterHints.enabled: false' does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

In order to hide this annoying hint overlay:

[image]

I have tried all the different approaches I am able to find:

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
"html.suggest.html5": false,
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```

Unfortunately, this thing still never goes away. I have even tried disabling all my React related extensions.

I also notice if I put `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` in 'Workspace Settings', it will work. But I really want to figure a way to apply this globally.

Any idea where have I overlooked? Could it be something else?

---

*Update*: I also realised the hint only triggers when I'm writing the styling object in React Native `StyleSheet.create()` function.

Comment: Try "The new javascript.suggest.enabled and typescript.suggest.enabled let you completely disable JS or TS suggestions."

Answer (score 0):

If its the same popup I just fixed, I found     "editor.quickSuggestions": null, changed to     "editor.quickSuggestions": false,
which worked.